# I am running 1.6.5, but the folder says 1.6.3?

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-due

I just downloaded the latest version of the Arduino software (1.6.5). However, when I look into the Application Support folder under Library (I have a mac), I find that I have a folder named 1.6.3:

Library ▸ Arduino15 ▸ packages ▸ arduino ▸ hardware ▸ sam ▸ 1.6.3

Does this mean there is a hidden 1.6.5 folder that I am not seeing?

BTW, this issue surfaced, because I am trying to fiddle around with the ADC clock speed, but it seems that nothing is happening:

```
void setup() {
  #define ADC_FREQ_MAX = 1;
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println(ADC_FREQ_MAX);
}

void loop() {
}
```

gives me:

```
opamp.ino: In function 'void setup()':
opamp:2: error: expected primary-expression before '=' token
opamp.ino:4:18: note: in expansion of macro 'ADC_FREQ_MAX'
opamp:4: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
opamp:4: error: expected ';' before ')' token
expected primary-expression before '=' token
```

Comment: It could simply be that the versions of code within that folder are at a level called 1.6.3.  Big applications are usually componentized which means that the release level of the app as a whole may be different from the release levels of its parts.  I could easily imagine that inside the 1.6.5 IDE there are parts that haven't changed since 1.6.3 and hence retain that version identity.

Comment: Ok, but I am changing the ADC frequency to like 1Hz, and I can't see any noticeable change, i.e. the analogRead() function still samples way faster than that - an apparent contradiction (I've even restarted the IDE)

Comment: Your define is incorrect, it should be `#define ADC_FREQ_MAX 1` only, no `=`, no `;`.

Comment: It's likely the different versions have been installed in different places - system wide vs. user-specific, etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because there isn't a single, specific clearly answerable question here, and the question has been abandoned in this state long enough that it is unlikely to ever be improved.

Answer (score 1):

1.6.5 is the version of the Arduino IDE.

1.6.3 is the version of the Arduino SAM Boards package that you have installed.

> Does this mean there is a hidden 1.6.5 folder that I am not seeing?

Library/Arduino15 is where your preferences.txt file and Boards Manager index files are stored. Library/Arduino15/packages is where hardware packages installed via **Tools > Board > Boards Manager** are stored. The Arduino IDE will be located elsewhere on your hard drive. If you need to find it here is an easy way:

1. **Tools > Examples > 01.Basics > BareMinimum**
2. **Sketch > Show Sketch Folder** - this will open the Examples/01.Basics/BareMinimum subfolder of the Arduino IDE installation folder.

> BTW, this issue surfaced...

That's off the topic of your question and already answered in a comment on your question so I will refrain from answering it.

Answer (score 0):

The error you see is because of the equal sign in your #define.  That equal should not be there. So the line that uses it ends up being.

Serial.println(= 1);

Which is obviously wrong.